# Как добавить в django форму, которая обрабатывает разные типы продуктов?

Tags: django

models - тут несколько моделей и хочу, чтобы пользователь смогу выбрать категорию товара и выложить на сайт товар

```
class Product(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name='Категория', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255,verbose_name='Наименование')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Изображение')
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описание', null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 9, decimal_places=2,verbose_name='Цена')
```

```
class Notebook(Product):
    diagonal = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Диагональ')
    display = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Тип дисплея')
    Processor_freq = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Частота ЦП')
class SmartPhones(Product):
    diagonal = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Диагональ')
    display = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Тип дисплея')
    sd = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Такие вещи нужно не хардкодить в моделях, а хранить в виде динамически меняемых строк ключ-значение (гуглите тему entity-attribute-value)